# Query performance in Netezza

Tags: performance, netezza

I don't know is this the right forum to ask the query-performance question in Netezza? If not, please let me know where should I post these types of questions?

Which of the below query will be more efficient?

```
--QUERY1:

UPDATE
S_F_PROMOTION_HISTORY
SET
  SENT_IND = SENT.SENT_IND,
  SEND_DT = SENT.SEND_DT
FROM
  (
    SELECT PROMO_HIST_ID, 1 AS SENT_IND, MIN(RESPONSE_DT) SEND_DT
    FROM
    S_STG_SMS_FEEDBACK
    WHERE
    RESPONSE_ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = 50
    GROUP BY
    PROMO_HIST_ID
 ) SENT
WHERE
S_F_PROMOTION_HISTORY.PROMO_HIST_ID = SENT.PROMO_HIST_ID;



--Query2:

CREATE TEMP TABLE SENT_TABLE AS
SELECT
  PROMO_HIST_ID, 1 AS SENT_IND, MIN(RESPONSE_DT) SEND_DT
FROM
  S_STG_SMS_FEEDBACK
WHERE
  RESPONSE_ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = 50
  GROUP BY PROMO_HIST_ID DISTRIBUTE ON PROMO_HIST_ID;

UPDATE
  S_F_PROMOTION_HISTORY
SET
  SENT_IND = SENT.SENT_IND,
  SEND_DT = SENT.SEND_DT
FROM 
  SENT_TABLE SENT 
WHERE 
  S_F_PROMOTION_HISTORY.PROMO_HIST_ID=SENT.PROMO_HIST_ID;
```

or are they equivalent as Temp table will also reside on the memory rather than disk and hence no difference because of same distribution keys for the tables on which join is happening?

In the second query, I broke the query into two parts and distribute the inner tables on the joining key and then updated the base table.